# CrashLoopBackOff when upgrading Node and Angular versions and deploying on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

I am in the process of upgrading the Node and Angular versions of my project. Locally, everything works fine, but when I deploy the files to Kubernetes, I encounter the following error when trying to access the web application from the browser:

```
503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
nginx
```

Upon checking the deployment status using kubeconfig, I noticed that the pod's status is showing as **CrashLoopBackOff**.

Upon closer inspection of the pod logs, I found the following error detail:

`Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.`

This error message about the cache seems confusing to me since I expect a clean state for each deployment, and there shouldn't be any traces of the previous deployment. Can someone explain what might be causing this error and why it mentions the cache?

**Complete Logs:**

```
> foods-sst-webapp@0.0.0 startserver
> node server.js

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /.npm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 5000:5000 "/.npm"

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /.npm/_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
```

Comment: Did you ever make and progress on this? 

It's quite frustrating, as there's not a ton of info on it and I've already followed all of the OpenShift guidance concerning supporting arbitrary user IDs from the root group. 

To make things more confusing in my situation, I have seen where I can deploy successfully to our DEV env and have everything just work, then I encounter this error when promoting the same image to QA. 

Most recently, I had one of my services go down expectedly, OpenShift restarted it, and this error appeared on the same build that was just running without issue.